# Can mongos be configured to talk to more than one mongo cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

The rule of thumb is to have the 'mongos' process running on each of your application servers. This keeps your application talking to localhost which is fast and your mongos processes scale with your app.

Say we have 2 distinct mongo clusters (sharded), is it possible to configure one mongos process to talk to two different clusters? It would be awesome to abstract away the fact that the databases lived in different places.

Or would you have to launch two different mongos processes on different ports? If this IS possible I still worry that it might be dangerous having two different mongos processes fighting for resources.

Or something completely different? Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each mongos belongs to one, only one, cluster (defined by the config db servers). The mongos processes don't use much resources; you can run multiple on a machine.

You can have more than one sharded db/collection per cluster.

Comment: Ok thanks... we want separate sharded clusters so we can scale each, independently. I did some research on the resources used by mongos and it is generally in the MB range.